# Smartphone NFC development

Tags: android, symbian, rfid, nfc

which NFC forum defined tags are you using?

We were using previously *NFC forum Tag 1* tags, which was was provided to us by Innovision company and were known under its sales name *Topaz*. Since the Innovision was bought by Broadcom the product disappear from the market. Are there any other *NFC forum Tag 1* providers? So far we are going with *NFC forum Tag 2* NXP Mifare UltraLight C, but they have half a capacity as Topaz had...

Which software and contactless readers are you using to write the data to the NFC tags?

BR
STeN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the tags I am using are mifare classic with 1k memory. I got them from smartcardfocus.com.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Anyone else has other experience?? Seems that Android 2.3.3 supports quite a wide range of NFC tags (compared to version 2.3)...

Answer (score 0):

i can see on the market only Mifare Ultralight (NFC Forum NDEF tag type 2) and Mifare classic - that's all. Other types I cannot see anywhere available for ordering in online shop to order. Especially Topaz tags...

Is everybody using Mifare?

Thanks
STeN

Answer (score 0):

mifare classic with 1k memory here, too.
Would try some others, but not avaiable (and if, only in 10.000 packages from china)

Answer (score 0):

I'm making my own, it uses NFC A (much like Type 2 tags)